Microsoft Fabric parametrize DataFlow Gen2
Lets say i want to get data from: https://gorest.co.in/public/v2/**users** and https://gorest.co.in/public/v2/**posts** with one dataflow. Using the copy data activity we could simply put it in a for each loop and parametize the enpoint. And then use one copy data activity to get all the enpoints we need.
Is there a way to do that in DataFlows Gen2? I tried using the generic JSON Connector and entering the URL as: "https://gorest.co.in/public/v2/@parameters.EndpointParameter" but that does not work.
I am thankful for any suggestions.

Each query should have a fixed schema, so that wouldn't really work.

It's far easier to do this parameter based approach in a data pipeline, and dump each api output to a Landing/apisubfolder area in OneLake, then add Gen2 to pick up stuff from there

Based on my understanding, as of today Dataflow Gen 2 in Fabric doesnt support any parameterization .
So you would have to create seperate ones per entity
